# Видеорежим в Borland Pascal

Tags: ассемблер, pascal, borland

**Задание:** Нарисовать в режиме 320х200 точек для видеоадаптера VGA окружность заданного радиуса.
*Работаю в Dosbox*
Реализовал вот так(Через биос прерывание):

```
Uses DOS;
var R:registers;
i,rad,...:integer;

Procedure SetVM; //Устанавливаем видеорежим через 10-е прерывание.
begin
  R.ah:=0;
  R.al:=$13;
  Intr($10,R);
end;

Procedure PutPixel();//процедура для отображения пикселя
begin
  R.ah:=$0C;
  R.al:=14;
  R.bh:=0;
  R.cx:=x;
  R.dx:=y;
  Intr($10,R);
end;
```

Далее просто рисую круг в цикле и т.д.

**Вопрос:** нужно реализовать тоже самое,но без прерываний,обращаясь напрямую к видеопамяти,ассемблер практически не понимаю,как это реализовать?

Comment: Нужно задать массив с указанием на память по адресу `$A000:0`, или работать с ней через `mem`, а дальше... Поищите в гугле по запросу "pascal видеопамять A000", например вот http://www.cyberforum.ru/pascalabc/thread391431.html. Ответ `Mem[A000:Off] := color;` Вот интересно, 13 видеорежим и правда людям интересен?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Упрощённый вариант доступа к видеопамяти для 13h видеорежима 320x200 256 цветов.

```
Procedure PutPixel(x:integere, y:integer, c:byte);
//процедура для отображения    пикселя
begin
      Mem[$a000:y*200 + x] := c;
end;
```

Для оптимизации. Можно сохранить в регистре ES (например) смещение, и обращатся в память через него. Но... любое использование "длинного" указателя стирает ES. Пример... как-то так:

```
my_ofs := y*200 +x;
asm
   mov ax,0A000h; это 
   mov es,ax; и это можно вынести из цикла
   mov bx, my_ofs;
   mov al,c;
   mov es:[bx],al;
end
```

В borland c++ это сделано лучше

```
 char _ES* v=0;
 _ES= 0xA000; // Задали ES
 v[y*200+x] = c;
```

Так же надо помнить, что операция умножения - затратная. Если копируется прямоугольная область, или рисуется ровная линия параленльная осям координат, то умножение на 200 можно вынести "за скобки".

Остальные способы я не могу быстро показать.
Просто перечислю:

1. Оптимизация алгоритма (тут можно писать много, в зависимости от задачи)
2. Оптимизация на уровне процессора. С использованием ассемблера, можно использовать 32,64,128 битные команды как 386 так и MMX и SSE набор. Цепные команды movsb stosb и т п. Максимально загрузить все регистры процессора для рисования нужной фигуры, даже если это просто копирование области.
3. Есть регистры палитры. Можно скинуть их все в ноль, и плавно восстановить. Можно делать эффект молний, не перерисовуя всю видеопамять. Можно дать одинаковый цвет двум цветам палитры и играть палитрой. Игра палитрой даст еффект скорости. Но такие спец-эффекты думаю устарели.
4. (не подходит для этого вопроса) Есть 3-D ускоритель карты, есть описание команд 10h прерывания. Есть OpegGL DirectX, читая статьи на эту тему - можно достичь максимально быстродействия.

Под этим видеорежимом делались очень старые игры. Ещё ссылки

1) http://pascal.sources.ru/articles/100.htm (тут + работа с палитрой)

Comment: Спасибо,мне преподаватель подсказал что есть вариант еще быстрее,Вы не знаете что это может быть?

Comment: Я говорил, 1) есть вариант создать массив c `^` ccылкой на адрес в памяти. Borland c++ и ассемблер, а отличии от паскаля, позволяет зафиксировать a000 например в es регистре, и обращатся к памяти минуя перезаписывание доп регистров. Можно оптимизировать умножение на 200. Есть DMA (отдельная тема).  2) Есть палитра(найдте в ссылках), ею можно кое-какие еффекты прикольно делать (плавное затухание или появление изображения). 3) есть аппаратное ускорение со своими приколами, часть которых доступна через  DirectX OpenGL, а часть через порты можно программировать (за рамками вопроса)